# How do I elegantly pass a lot of method pointers to a DLL written in C?

Tags: c, delphi, pointers, dll

I have a Delphi-Firemonkey application which manages a part of its network communications through a DLL based library written in C. As the purpose is network management the library provides methods and also requires methods from the associated application. The DLL has only one main class. The class is written in such a way that it starts its works immediately after its object is created i.e. no control variables like active or enabled etc.

Due to incompatibilities between both languages, only simple methods can be accessed. So I pass their pointers to the constructor of the class in the DLL.

Now, I have to address a lot more such methods which must be callable from within the DLL. Please guide me to an appropriate solution.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, or what it has to do with Delphi. Your question mentions C and C++ - why isn't it tagged with those instead? There's not even a mention of Delphi anywhere in your post. (And no, a standard TList is not appropriate for passing across process boundaries or interop.)

Comment: @KenWhite will an array of pointers do?

Comment: You cannot call a Delphi method from C. You can only call non-instance  functions and procedures. If you showed some code we might understand you better.

Comment: you may create a COM Object in Delphi with all the methods required and pass its *interface* to the DLL. The DLL would then use this COM/OLE object and call its methods when see fit.

Comment: @Arioch'The though its a great thing to do, its too much work (my understanding originates from Rudy's blogged method). I will only think about it when I do get to a more stable version.

Comment: I don't remember having blogged about it, but in one of my articles I do describe a method to call C++ from Delphi and how to write the C++ code. The proposal here is the other way around, and in Delphi, it is pretty easy to write an interface and have it implemented by a class.

Comment: @Arioch'The what will be the upside of this method against Remy's solution?

Comment: OLE/COM and IDispatch were designed for call-based object-oriented languages interaction. You would have to do a lot more of boilerplate (which would somewhat slow down both development and execution, especially IDispatch), but in result you might get a much richer interactions (set of allowed data types including objects from 3rd languages) and (if done right) kind of compile-time syntax checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a C DLL which further addresses multiple C++ DLLs.

The fact that the C DLL interacts with C++ DLLs is completely irrelevant.  Your real question is  only related to the interaction between your Delphi code and the C DLL.  Leave it at that.

> For making the DLL able to call methods from the delphi application, I was passing them as pointers to the C DLL.

C (or C++ for that matter) cannot call Delphi object instance methods.  You can only use non-instance function/procedures instead.  In that regard, yes, you have to pas them as pointers (and make sure you have declared them correctly in C to match their declarations in Delphi, including calling conventions, which is very important).

> Now I have to add like 20 more such methods. To not compromise readability I think passing a method pointer list's pointer should be a good idea. I have never made a method pointer list before.
>
> The DLL objects immediately start processing after creation so I need to pass the pointers to their constructor.

You can have the Delphi code pass a pointer to a `record` (a `struct` in C) that contains the function pointers.  You can then add more pointers to that record in the future if needed.  The DLL can copy the function pointers from the `record`/`struct` and store them somewhere that the objects can find them.

For example:

Delphi:

```
type
  TGetValueFuncType = function: Integer; cdecl;
  ...
  TDllFuncPtrs = record
    GetValueFunc: TGetValueFuncType;
  end;

procedure DllSetFuncPtrs(var FuncPtrs: TGetValueFuncType); stdcall; external 'C.dll' name 'SetFuncPtrs';

...

function GetValue: Integer; cdecl;
begin
  Result := 12345;
end;

...

var
  FuncPtrs: TDllFuncPtrs;
begin
  FuncPtrs.GetValueFunc := @GetValue;
  ...
  DllSetFuncPtrs(FuncPtrs);
end;
```

C:

```
struct TDllFuncPtrs
{
    int __cdecl (*GetValueFunc)(void);
    ...
};

TDllFuncPtrs gFuncPtrs = {0};

__declspec(dllexport)
void __stdcall SetFuncPtrs(TDllFuncPtrs *FuncPtrs)
{
    gFuncPtrs = *FuncPtrs;
}

...

void DoSomething()
{
    int Value = 0;
    if (gFuncPtrs.GetValueFunc != NULL)
        Value = gFuncPtrs.GetValueFunc();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you provide pros and cons to both your and Ken White's proposal of making the exe export methods?

Comment: Exporting functions from the EXE means the DLL has to have specific knowledge of the EXE's existence, which prevents the DLL from being used by other DLLs, or migrating the EXE to another language that does not export functions from EXEs, should you ever need to make those changes in the future.  Having the caller (EXE or otherwise) pass the required function pointers to the DLL is more flexible, portable, and future proof.